# Redux-thunk applyMiddleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Just wondering why in this setup he put thunk in array and spread the middleware argument what is the difference between by just passing applyMiddleware (thunk).

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is none. It is just preference, if you check the applyMiddleware signature it can take up to 5 middleware directly or if you want more than that you need this syntax.